# SKAudioNode not load sound from url

Tags: ios, swift, skaudionode

I want download sound from url and play it once:

```
let sound = SKAudioNode(url:URL(string:"http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/a2002011001-e02-16kHz.wav")!)

sound.run(SKAction.play())
```

I tried `.mp3` music too. It doesn't download it or stream and returns: `nil`

But this code cause error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false:
>   file != nil'
>   *** First throw call stack:  ....
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

Comment: cehck once you have get here is nil or output

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes, but why i get nil. audio exists...

Comment: check this URL(string: '

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik :   http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/a2002011001-e02-16kHz.wav

Comment: @Arti your problem solve now ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya yes, i solved problem with `AVAudioPlayer` thank you, but why `SKAudioNode` it's weird.

Comment: i m not good in this topic but i know little about SKAudiNode its help you when you want to play .wav file then its help you and Its a protocol of AVAudio3DMixing and AVAudioplyer is best to perform to play any audio with extension .wav ,.mp3 ,m4r , m4p , avr file and much more i give more important to AVAudioplayer .

Comment: @Arti got it ? why i use AVAudioPlayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you try `AVAudioPlayer`

```
var resourcePath = url  //your url
var objectData = Data(contentsOf: NSURL(string: resourcePath)!)
var error: Error!
do {
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(objectData)
}
catch let error {
}
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0
audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
if audioPlayer == nil {
    print("\(error.description)")
}
else {
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the URL needed os the URL for the resource that you must have in your app bundle. Put the mp3 file in your project and then do this-

```
let urlpath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "[name of file]", ofType: "mp3")
let audioURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: urlpath!)

let sound = SKAudioNode(url: audioURL)

sound.run(SKAction.play())
```