# App crashing on AVAudioRecorder Initialisation with url in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, avaudiorecorder

This code was working fine in other project in swift 2.3. But As I am trying to implement it in swift 3.0, I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS. in

```
 audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: self.directoryURL() as! URL , settings: settings)
```

Code:

```
func setUpAudioRecording()

{
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        ]

        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: self.directoryURL() as! URL , settings: settings)
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
        audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    }
    catch let error
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    }

    func directoryURL() -> NSURL? {
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let audioURL = url.appendingPathComponent("recording.3gp")
        return audioURL as NSURL?
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40079765/6656894 refer this

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Given link is for AVAudioPlayer. I am using Recorder.

Comment: 3gp this format is not working in audio use .caf file and check it

Comment: Not working. Its Crashing on the same line.

Comment: I was initailising the AVAudioPlayer twice. Thats why it crashed.

Comment: Ya now only one time initailise it and check it