# AVQueuePlayer is taking lot of time to play first song

Tags: ios, swift, avqueueplayer

Below is my code to play AVQueueplayer with some web URL, but it takes almost 10-20 seconds to play first song. I have 10 songs, but for reference and to make it small, I have just kept one song here.

```
    arrSongs = ["http://radiotaj.com/music/1/1836.mp3"]
    let index = 0
    let strSong = (arrSongs.object(at: index)) as? String
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string:strSong!)!
    let playerItems = [playerItem]
    player = AVQueuePlayer(items : playerItems as! [AVPlayerItem])
    player.play()
```

Below are the solutions I have already tried

1. Adding CMTime
2. Making it pause and play again
3. It works perfectly fine if file is local.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40079765/6656894 refer this answer

Comment: Doesn't work. It's AVPlayer. I need it for AVQueuePlayer and that too in SWIFT

Comment: if you have single url for play audio then i suggest you to use AVPlayer and in multiple urls then use AVQueuePlayer

Comment: Yes correct. If you see in my question only I have mentioned, I have 10 songs to play. Just for sample, I have given one. I need to make this AVQueuePlayer work. Your any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: then use NSNotificationCenter in your player like [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[theItems lastObject]]; // is theItems your array of url and pass last object in that

Comment: Why would it need any Notification? Did you ready my question, it's lagging in playing first song only. Other songs there is no issue. Only first song's lagging is big.

Comment: You can just try running my code into your xCode and see, it's just 10 lines code and player is AVQueuePlayer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code, it works for me. Here is the version without Alamofire (replace `yourURL` with the actual link):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    downloadFileFromURL(url: URL(string: yourURL)!)
}

 func play(url: URL) {
    do {
        let songData = try Data(contentsOf: url, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(data: songData, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeAppleM4A)
        player!.prepareToPlay()
        player!.play()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}


func downloadFileFromURL(url: URL) {
    var downloadTask = URLSessionDownloadTask()
    downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
        customURL, response, error in

        self.play(url: customURL!)
    })
    downloadTask.resume()
}
```

Using Alamofire is faster, it basically downloads the file into the Documents folder and plays it from here (don't forget to install Alamofire and type outside the class `import Alamofire`:

```
func play(url: URL) {
    do {
        let songData = try Data(contentsOf: url, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(data: songData, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeAppleM4A)
        player!.prepareToPlay()
        player!.play()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
        var documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        documentsURL.appendPathComponent("song."+"mp3")
        return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile])
    }

    Alamofire.download(yourURL, to: destination).response { response in
        if response.destinationURL != nil {
            songURL = response.destinationURL!
            self.play(url: songURL!)
        }
    }
}
```